# Tweeting as different user using REST API

Tags: twitter

I'm currently writing a shop-related site that has it's own community in different social networks. While posting to VKontakte and Facebook is less of an issue (I can understand the concept of "group", and VK actually has an option to write posts using the group's name), Twitter is more troublesome.

**Two questions:**

1. Is there even such a thing as "groups" in Twitter? The closest I have seen is [lists](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-using-twitter-lists) and [timelines](https://support.twitter.com/articles/164083-what-s-a-twitter-timeline), but neither appears to solve my issue.
2. I cannot give the operator access to the twitter account. VK has a specific option when posting in a group to use that group's name as poster name. How does this work in Twitter?

I need something akin to what [lamoda](https://twitter.com/lamoda_rus) has set up. (It appears to be a user, and every post is labeled as written by that user, however I doubt they give their ops access to the actual twitter account).

*P.S.: I'm already done with getting past OAuth and using REST to actually post, thus no code provided. I'm just having trouble with the statuses/update.json call, if that's what I should actually be using.*

Comment: Still stuck, I'm afraid. SO is my only hope at the moment. Further research proved futile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk about simple solutions to simple problems.

It appears I have been overcomplicating. There are no groups in twitter, or even comments at that. You can only post to your own feed or re-post from somebody else's.

Posting to someone's feed (a shop account's, say) is simple enough using that account's pre-generated access token which can be stored in the configs.